# Spark submit on Yarn Cluster mode with config file put into HDFS issue

Tags: java, apache-spark, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn

I have a spark program that needs to be passed a config file as a parameter for the main method. Currently when I submit the job in yarn cluster mode, I need to put the config file in all worker nodes so that the program can find it. However, I want to put it into HDFS path but will get the file not found error. Below is the command I use:

```
spark-submit --master yarn\
--name StreamingApp \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--class com.test.streaming.App \
--driver-java-options "-Djava.security.auth.login=/home/spark/auth.conf" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/spark/auth.conf" \
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/spark/auth.conf" \
--conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/etc/hbase/conf/" \
/home/spark/StreamingFramework-0.0.1-SNAPSHTO-jar-with-dependencies.jar /home/spark/config.json
```

How can I put the last parameter (**/home/spark/config.json**) into HDFS so it works?

Answer (score 0):

Need some clarity with regards to the usage of this config file here.

In case it is just needed as an argument to the main method, & the content is being used for spark session initialisation, then there should be no need to copy it onto any of the worker nodes.

In case the file is needed in the driver or the executors, then you should be passing it using the `--files` argument.

Copying to hdfs from local can be done using https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#copyFromLocal

Comment: Actually this config file will contain some Kafka bootstrap, Zookeeper, Hbase, etc info. And will give some sql query there. The spark program will read those info to connect to the kafka and database to get message and write the changes into tables. Those info will not relate to the spark session, will only impact the kafka and hbase connection.